# How to draw a triangle by using QGraphicsView's QGraphicsItem class

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I want to draw a triangular object in `QGraphicsView` by using `QGraphicsItem`. But I don't know how to implement bounding rect according to triangler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a `QGraphicsPolygonItem`.

You just have to describe a triangle polygon with `QPolygonF` and then add it to your scene with [QGraphicsScene::addPolygon()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addPolygon).

```
// Describe a closed triangle
QPolygonF Triangle;
Triangle.append(QPointF(-10.,0));
Triangle.append(QPointF(0.,-10));
Triangle.append(QPointF(10.,0));
Triangle.append(QPointF(-10.,0));

// Add the triangle polygon to the scene
QGraphicsPolygonItem* pTriangleItem = pScene->addPolygon(Triangle);
```

This way, everything is handled by Qt, you don't have to worry about bounding rect.

Comment: but how can i detect  collision ?

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz : have a look at [QGraphicsScene::collidesWithItem()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsitem.html#collidesWithItem)

Answer (score 0):

To draw triangle you need 3 points and draw the line between them. Subclass the `QGraphicsItem` and in the paint method of subclass class draw triangle later set the item to `QGraphicsScene` then add the scene to `QGraphicsView`.